audio-mixer Independent from Device-Volume
I'm developing a C# program, and I needs to play audio independently of the system
audio-mixer.
I can't seem to figure out how to play audio independently of the system-mixer, what I want is to play audio without being affected by the system audio-mixer, so if a user has there system audio at 10% or 50% it would still play audio from my program at the same volume.
The program should be able to play audio while other programs are also playing audio, with this program being audio-independent and other programs being audio-dependent.
Note: The audio should not be affected by both system and program volume (that's what N-Audio seems to do); it should only be affected by its own mixer.
I tried using N-audio with a couple approaches but none of them seem to work, I tried using AudioClientShareMode.Shared and AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive but both didn't work, here is that:
        WasapiOut waveOutDevice;
        AudioFileReader audioFileReader;

        waveOutDevice = new WasapiOut(AudioClientShareMode.Shared, 0);
        audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(filePath) { Volume = volume };
        waveOutDevice.Init(audioFileReader);

        waveOutDevice.Play();

and the same thing but with waveOutDevice = new WasapiOut(AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive, 0); instead.
the first one (AudioClientShareMode.Shared) just doesn't work, and the second one (AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive) just throws System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: '0x88890016'l..

You will hopefully not achieve what you want, since there is a reason, system settings are prevalent. It this is something like an alarm bell or so, you might want to use an extra hardware device, e.g. via USB?

no, this is not a alarm or something physical and I don't have a USB, I got it half working with the example I showed with N-audio using AudioClientShareMode.Exclusive were the user's system-volume did not impact the volume of my program BUT It could not play other audio from other programs which is the problem.
